# How to make use of environment parameter passed to EntityFramework Core CLI

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Some of Entity Framework Core CLI commands accept `environment` parameter. For example `dotnet ef migrations list --environment <env_name>`.

The assembly where I keep migrations is separate from data entities assembly, therefore I had to derive from `IDbContextFactory`.

And here comes my question: is there a way to get the environment parameter passed to CLI from inside my `DbContextFactory` class? I need this to apply specific environment's connections strings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stupid me, after the day of looking around, I noticed that `Create` method of `IDbContextFactory` interface has the parameter of type `DbContextFactoryOptions`, which in turn has `EnvironmentName` property, which appears to be the one passed to CLI commands.

Case closed.

Comment: Kudos to the smart people using EF Core despite the serious lack of documentation! Hopefully this gets covered by [aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs#204](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/204).

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Core and EF Core 2.0.1**

In order to grant elevated permissions for migrating entity changes while maintain lower privileges for the application, two SQL users were created.

The connection information for the application is stored in `appsettings.json`.  The connection information for use with the EF CLI is stored in `appsettings.<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>.json`.  Both use the same `ConnectionStrings` key.

For the `dotnet ef` to execute successfully, the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set before attempting to update the database.

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>
dotnet ef database update
```